# To which magnetic pole would a positive charge entering from space move to?

Tags: electromagnetism

Does the charge of an ion, be it negative or positive, have an effect on which pole it will move towards on Earth, or will the charge only determine the helical motion (clockwise or anticlockwise) rotation of the said charge? What connection is there between these charges and the north and south poles of a magnetic field?

Answer (score 1):

A charge is not attracted to magnetic poles.  Rather, a magnetic field induces a force on a moving charge in a direction perpendicular to both the velocity of the charge and the direction of the magnetic field.

However, a charge whose velocity has a component parallel to the magnetic field will tend to spiral along the magnetic field lines. So, a charge that's spiralling around the field lines above the equator will move generally toward one of the poles. But, because the field lines are closer together near the poles, the spiralling gets tighter, the angle of the spiral changes, and the charge turns around and spirals back in the reverse direction.  It ends up going back and forth, approaching but not reaching both poles.